# how to create a new table having json record from a kusto table

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

We receive a multiline json (in format below), and we store them into a Kusto table "OldT" after using multiline json mapping.

```
{"severity":"0","hostname":"Test.login","sender":"Test.login","body":"2a09dfa1","facility":"1","version":"1","timestamp":"2020-04-23T07:07:06.077963Z"}
{"severity":"0","hostname":"Test.login","sender":"Test.login","body":"2a09dfa1","facility":"1","version":"1","timestamp":"2020-04-23T07:07:00.893151Z"}
```

Records in table "OldT":

```
sender      timestamp                   severity    version body    priority    facility    hostname

Test.login  2020-04-23T07:07:06.077963  0           2a09dfa1        1     Test.login
Test.login  2020-04-23T07:07:00.893151Z 0           2a09dfa1        1     Test.login
```

Now I need to move the data into another table, say "`NewT`" with only one column, say "`Rawrecord`"

Rawrecord:

```
{"severity":"0","hostname":"Test.login","sender":"Test.login","body":"2a09dfa1","facility":"1","version":"1","timestamp":"2020-04-23T07:07:06.077963Z"}
{"severity":"0","hostname":"Test.login","sender":"Test.login","body":"2a09dfa1","facility":"1","version":"1","timestamp":"2020-04-23T07:07:00.893151Z"}
```

How can I move this data to `NewT`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [pack_all()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/packallfunction) function. For example:

```
OldT | project Rawrecord = pack_all()
```

To move it to another table you can use the [.set-or-append](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/data-ingestion/ingest-from-query) command for example:

```
.set-or-append NewT <| OldT | project Rawrecord = pack_all()
```